# Why does my rewrite rule disables additional $_GET data?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm using this rewrite rule for my whole domain:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9/-]+)$ /index.php?path=$1
```

So for example, my urls look like this:

http://www.example.com/page/subpage/4/anything/

The problem is when I want to manually add a specific `$_GET`, like this:

http://www.example.com/page/subpage/4/anything/?also=admin

I remember this has worked on some sites I've been developing, but it doesn't work here.

How can I fix my RewriteRule so that I can add `$_GET` data like this?

Comment: `=` is not included in the regex at all for instance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Query String Append (QSA)](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString):

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9/-]+)$ /index.php?path=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Making it CW because this has a bazillion duplicates... they are just very hard to search for.

Comment: feel free to edit my question to rename the title, should it make others easier to search for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add as second rule that looks for URLs with ? in them:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9/-]+)\?(.*) /index.php?path=$1&$2
```